# In vim, is it possible to set a particular line text into a specific color without defining syntax?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, syntax

Is it possible to get around syntax, and set text color directly in vim?

Comment: @muru That's ALMOST what I need. But I want to be able to `matchdelete` an id from another window instead of current window. Any way to do that?

Comment: It seems it's because I'm using nvim, and nvim doesn't support `matchdelete` with winnr yet...........